# Csharp Swapping Dynamic values in string

Tags: c#

I want to swap two values in a STRING
This is an example of doing it with characters:

string str = "PQRQP";

```
  var res= str.Select(a=> a == 'P' ? 'Q' : (a=='Q' ? 'P' : a)).ToArray();
  str = new String(res);

  Console.WriteLine(str);
```

But my string is 2/7/2019, where i want to swap the 2 and 7 each time but as these values are from user input i wont know what they will be before runtime.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance !

-----------MY SOLUTION----------------

```
            String values = DateRangePicker1.Value.ToString();
            String startDate = values.Substring(0, 8);
            String endDate = values.Substring(11, 8);
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            String newSDate = date.ToString();
            String newEDate = date1.ToString();
            String finalSDate = newSDate.Substring(0, 10);
            String finalEDate = newEDate.Substring(0, 10);
```

I know this is slightly messy, but is working for me without affecting performance

Comment: This is an XY problem.  You're probably working with a datetime?  If not, you should be parsing this into one and utilize `ToString` to get your desired format.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: You want the user to input a date as string, and swap the day with the month?

Comment: Also, can you clarify why you want to do this?

Comment: @Innominatum Probably the difference between m/d/yyyy and d/m/yyyy

Comment: @Innominatum  exactly but I cant parse to date/time as it causes  other issues

Comment: @EJoshuaS I am reading from a date picker into a string, querying the database only works as a string because of particular triggers, i have only read access for this particular project, hope this makes it clearer

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 i have tried to parse to date/time but because date is missing zeros 2/2/2019 it wont let me format it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rather seems to be a localization issue (based on the fact that you are providing a string that looks like a date)

Is it possible that by just providing the correct date annotation that this would solve your problem?

```
DateTime.ParseExact(string)
```

for instance is a method that allows you to create a datetime object from a string, if you tell it what the string format is

example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2/1/2019", "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

will provide a datetime object set to the first of febuary 2019. You can then convert the datetime object to a string with:

```
date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
output: 01-02-19
```

Edit: if you have a range of acceptable formats, it is possible to provide an array of formats in string form.

Comment: this would work if it was the same date each time, but the date changes dynamically so cant hardcode

Comment: You can hardcode the format (the second parameter to `ParseExact`).  The first parameter is a string that you will parse.  You can pass it any string that represents a date in _[one or two digit month]/[one or two digit day of month]/[four digit year] format_.

Comment: @juniordev101 thats what I'm saying in the edit. If you have a range of dates that are acceptable you can provide it with an array of acceptable formats. It is not going to suddenly provide you with a ssmmhhddMMyy format will it? Regardless, your best bet would be to create DateTime objects and to convert them that way

Answer (score 0):

You can use split to get the charachters you dont know.
Like this:

```
var sepratedInput = input.split('/');
var res= sepratedInput[1] +"/"+sepratedInput[0]+"/"+sepratedInput[2];
Console.write(res);
```

Comment: For your info, this might work as well. All you need to check is what the number divider (like "/", "-", "_", ",") and then split it on that char.